# Allow File to be Read by Non-Admin User Process

Tags: windows, nsis, file-permissions, user-permissions

My installer runs with elevated privileges and writes a file (A) to `$APPDATA` (C:/ProgramData) aswell as writting files to `$PROGRAMFILES`. File `A` is a `.addin` file read by an application called Revit.

**My Problem:** Because the file `A` is created by an admin process, this file is unable to be read by Revit when the user is a Non-Admin windows user.

I would like to edit the file `A` **so that it can be read by the a Non-Admin windows user** but I dont know how. Can you suggest how I can achieve this?

I have tried using the NSIS function `SetFileAttributes "myFilePath.addin" NORMAL` but this doesn't work.

**Note:** I am aware I could run my installer without elevated privileges and then Revit could read the file but as I mentioned above my installer also writes to `$PROGRAMFILES` so I need elevated privileges.

Comment: $APPDATA is not C:\ProgramData unless you did `SetShellVarContext all` first. Can you please clarify if you are talking about a users %APPDATA% or the shared %ALLUSERSPROFILE%?

Comment: Files under %ALLUSERSPROFILE% and %PROGRAMDATA% are not supposed to be modified by non-administrators. This is a shared location and things break when multiple users change the file. (Two different users could access the file at the same time when using "Switch Users" or Remote Desktop!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AccessControl plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) to change the DACL:

```
; This gives read access to the everyone group, use (BU) or (S-1-5-32-545) for BUILTIN\Users
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$INSTDIR\myfile" "(S-1-1-0)" "GenericRead"
```

Comment: thanks very much that worked just as needed. Thanks for your quick reply too :D

Comment: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=16849339 does not really specify which rights are required so I'm sure generic read is fine. http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2014/ENU/?guid=GUID-4FFDB03E-6936-417C-9772-8FC258A261F7 shows that per-user $appdata installs are also possible.

Comment: I'm guessing this might be related to "System objects: Default owner for objects created by members of the Administrators group", a setting that depends on the OS version and workstation vs server. If this is set to false you would own the file and have access...

Comment: um yeah Civil Engineering firms have their computers locked up like fort knox by their IT guys. Each Civil Engineer/Architect is a restricted user. Asking the IT guys to change a computers permissions and settings and give an inch of 'room for movement' to a civil engineer is going to be harder than solving the mid-east crisis